# C# adding a "IIS AppPool\AppPoolName" to a certificate

Tags: c#, iis, permissions, certificate, sql-grant

I have sort code in which i want to add user (IIS AppPool\name) to certificate,but always invalid a specified username. How to can i add valid IIS AppPool\name?

If i add localname\IIS AppPool\name invalid

Comment: You have to edit the question to include the exact code, because "add user to certificate" is an ambiguous description and impossible for others to guess what you exactly wanted to do.

Comment: How did you add the user (IIS AppPool\name) to the certificate, can you describe your steps in detail? I suggest you edit your question to add more useful information, and you can also post the screenshot of the error.